# No loop while switching the tabs in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, shortcut

Is there any way to set the loop on while switching the tabs from last to first?
eg. when you press (Ctrl + tab) or similar on last tab, it doesn't redirect to first tab like in browsers.

any way to set it ON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best you can get is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> (go to the left tabs)

and

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> (go to the right tabs)

I don't know if there is a circular option (and I really believe there is no circular option like browsers do), but maybe you can use
<kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>←</kbd> 
or
<kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>→</kbd>

This is the opening/closing order of the tabs.